# How to remove a whitespace in php even if its not detected

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to remove a whitespace from a string, but this whitespace its not detected, i've tried so many solutions like `str_replace()`, `preg_replace()` `htmlentities()` an `html_entity_decode()` but its not working because i can't detect this whitespace even if it's really present.

So any ideas please ?

An example : 7412 148 ==> The goal is : 7412148 
PS : i've tried to convert it to INT (not working) !

Thanks

Comment: where does the string come from and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Try `preg_replace("/\\s/u", "", $s)`.

Comment: is the whitespace at the beginning, the end or inside the string, can you provide some sample so we can get a better understanding?

Comment: the string returned from a function, when i do a var_dump() i can see that's a string.

Comment: @AlexAndrei i've added an example on the question !

Comment: @karimkarim There might be a case that some hidden characters exist instead of whitespace. And somehow browser could not render that character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `preg_replace` to replace/remove everything that is not a digit.

```
$str = "1234 5657"; // this is an example

$number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$str);

print $number;
```

Use this with the string that your function returns and let us know if it works.

Comment: it's working, thanks a lot !